# Why are folders not interpreted correctly in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, filesystemobject

Today, I need some help with a batch-file, that compares folders.
I am working an a virtual windows 10 machine, if this is needed to know.

Depending, where I store my file, the comparsion works fine.(e.g. if I store it in Z:\Projektdaten)
If I store it e.g. on my virtual desktop, it compares something unknown". 
Then I get an error like "system could not find the file", as often as much files are located there

Here is my file:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM --- Dokumente Variablen setzen ---
Set localdrive=Z:\Projektdaten\parts\electrical\
Set remotedrive=G:\Projectdata\parts\electrical\


CALL :Compare %localdrive%, %remotedrive%, "amplifiers_controllers\general"

pause

EXIT

:Compare
Set localfolder=%~1%~3
Set remotefolder=%~2%~3

if not exist "%localfolder%\" mkdir "%localfolder%\
if not exist "%remotefolder%\" mkdir "%remotefolder%\

echo COPY TO SERVER: %localfolder%
cd %localfolder% & for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist %remotefolder%"\%%i" copy %localfolder%"\%%i" %remotefolder%"\%%i"
echo COPY TO LOCAL:  %remotefolder%
cd %remotefolder% & for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist %localfolder%"\%%i" copy %remotefolder%"\%%i" %localfolder%"\%%i"
```

Comment: Just to fix your supplied code Line 20: `if not exist "%localfolder%\" mkdir "%localfolder%"`, Line 21: `if not exist "%remotefolder%\" mkdir "%remotefolder%"`, Line 24: `cd /d "%localfolder%" && for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist "%remotefolder%\%%i" copy "%%i" "%remotefolder%"` Line 26: `cd /d "%remotefolder%" && for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist "%localfolder%\%%i" copy "%%i" "%localfolder%"`. However, for the task you appear to be performing, you could probably do it much more simply using `Robocopy.exe`. Please also open a Command Prompt window, type `cd /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: The arguments to the called subroutine are space-separated, not comma-separated. Be careful with directory names containing spaces.

Comment: The comma is an argument delimiter too @k314159, and multiple concurrent delimiters count as one, so whilst the comma is unnecessary, it also does not cause an issue, and may help a little with some readers understanding.

Comment: Ok, guys, thanks for help. Compo, your hint was gold but ther have been some other issues with spaces. I solved it.

Comment: @Compo thanks, that's one more thing I've learned today. Btw I think you mean multiple consecutive delimiters. My mind blows up when I try to think what "concurrent delimiters" are.

Comment: Yes I meant consecutive @k314159! Telefisch I have removed your latest edit, please do not add solutions to your question, there is an answer area specifically for answers. Also please be aware that nothing I posted in my previous comment required, or should have been changed, with respect to your posted code. There were improvements you could have made elsewhere, but those were irrespective of what I posted to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Compo, I hope that is the way you like it?
Sorry, only wanted others to help with my solution.
The rules here are a bit different to other platforms.
Sorry for that!

The solution:

```
::Setting up the vars , using the parameters
Set localfolder="%~1%~3"
Set remotefolder="%~2%~3"

::Creating missing folders
if not exist %localfolder%\ mkdir %localfolder%\
if not exist %remotefolder%\ mkdir %remotefolder%\

echo COPY TO SERVER: %localfolder%
cd /d %localfolder% && for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist %remotefolder%\%%i copy "%%i" %remotefolder%
echo COPY TO LOCAL:  %remotefolder%
cd /d %remotefolder% && for %%i in (*.*) do if not exist %localfolder%\%%i copy "%%i" %localfolder%
```